# Twitter API Local Trend Parsing - stdClass Error

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, twitter, stdclass

I'm trying to parse the latest Twitter trend from a location (Atlanta in this case)

Here's my code:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <?php
     $init = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/2357024.json?count=1&callback=?&exclude=hashtags';
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$init);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     $obj = json_decode($result);
     foreach ($obj[0]->trends as $trend) {
     echo "<li class=\"atlanta\">".$trend->name."</li>";
}?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The desired result would be `<li class="atlanta">Whatever The Trend Is</li>`

It works about 30% of the time - but the other 70% I get this error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...

After some googling it seems the obj must be array... The only answer I've found is to change the $obj line to a true like this:

```
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
```

However, that simply gives me this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...

Does anyone know how to change my code into an 'array' so that it will work 100% of the time?

Comment: You need to add in error handler to catch any unforeseen error (like network down in your server to twitter) before parse using json_decode

Comment: Please check out my edit for how to format posts on SO. It hurts my feelings that you did not bother to read the painstakingly-compiled FAQ that was shown to you prominently alongside the box where you wrote your question.

Answer (score 0):

@Ken: Try

```
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
if (is_array($obj)) { 
    foreach ($obj[0]->trends as $trend) {
        echo "<li class=\"atlanta\">" . $trend->name . "</li>";
    }
} else {
   // failure case here
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I tried that fix, However I am still getting this error:       Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() .....